# mysql host from which user can connect issues

Tags: asp.net, mysql, iis-6

We have a web app that we are deploying to a test IIS 6 web server.  The app works fine on the production server running IIS 6 and on a dev server running IIS 7.  In the new test server we are having problems with the app connecting to mysql.

Here is what we have found/know so far.  In mysql, for the user specified in the connect strings, there is a list of hosts (ip addresses and wild card addresses) which are allowed for that user to connect.   We were unable to connect with mysql admin until we added the new server IP to this list.   None of the other ip addresses have any schema privileges assigned but with my local workstation, and the IIS 7 dev server, we can log in to mysql admin and see all the catalogs.   On the new box we log in but no catalogs are available.   When I look at the server connections I see the new IP address with a blank DB column and the only catalogs showing up are information_schema and test.    And of course the web app won't get past the login page because there is no database to authenticate the user.

It seems to be specifically related to something in the mysql side of the equation.  Anyone have any suggestions or ideas on what it is we are missing configuration to resolve this?

Comment: Ok we kind of figured it out.   It was an issue with the grants for the user being based on the IP the user accesses the database from.   The user we use for the connect string has every permission EXCEPT grant so even though we could add a new IP host, that host was limited to only having Usage permissions.   Once we tracked down the SA user and which IP address was allowed to grant the appropriate permissions, we were able to access the database from mysql but we still can't get the website to talk to the database. Not sure if it is an additional MySql or an IIS config that we're missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  After updating the Mysql user hosts and getting the right permissions, we updated all the server name references to IP address and then had to resolve some issues with the firewall/proxy access between this dmz and the zone that has the database servers.